# Parametrizing this curve

Tags: complex-analysis, parametric

How can I parametrize the trajectory

[image: this guy]

so that it is a smooth path $h:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$?

I think that I should use $$h=\left\{\begin{array}{ccl}t+i |t|&:&-1\leq t \leq 0\\
? &:&0\leq t \leq 1\end{array}\right.$$
but I'm not sure what to put for $?$ to make it smooth.

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate.  I couldn't find it in the search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parametrization $h : t \mapsto \left\{ \begin{matrix} \exp \left( 1- \frac{1}{t^2} \right) (1,-1) & \text{if} \ t<0 \\ \exp \left( 1- \frac{1}{t^2} \right) (1,1) & \text{if} \ t>0 \\ 0 & \text{if} \ t=0 \end{matrix} \right.$ is even $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$. However, the derivative of any parametrization is zero at $(0,0)$ since the slope of the tangents is discontinuous at this point.

Comment: That's the one, nice, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is not smooth. Under no parametrization will it become smooth.

Comment: @julien It depends on the exact definition of smooth. (In some books, it is required that the derivative of the paramatrization is non-zero.)

Comment: @mrf Yes, and now that I think about it, they're right. In a manifold context, one would understand smooth parametrization by smooth diffeormorphism.

Comment: @julien I also think that is the better definition. But there seems to be no consensus among textbook authors.